# BigQuery outage on 29th Oct 2019?

Tags: google-bigquery

Our App Engine application logs show that the instances couldn't connect to BigQuery starting at 3:43AM 30th Oct 2019 Australian Eastern Standard Time.

```
https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[my-project-name]/datasets/[my-dataset-name]/tables/events/insertAll?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: dial tcp [2607:f8b0:4001:c07::5f]:443: i/o timeout
```

I checked the States page (https://status.cloud.google.com/) and no outage is reported.

Does anyone notice this issue? Or maybe it's a network issue in our VPC?

Comment: You can raise a case with support and they would be able to provide much more detail on the issue, but I am not aware of any outage for BQ on 29th October.

Comment: As @jjayadeep noted above, this topic can be better addressed by directly contacting Google by [creating an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) on Google Issue Tracker

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support issue, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue with go runtime 111, which experiences network connection issue to other services such as cloud sql and bigquery. It's been raised to customer support and being investigated.